# How to produce tidy summaries when comparing logical conditions

Tags: r, count, data-visualization, logical-operators, summary

Consider the following data frame:

```
set.seed(123)
dat <- data.frame(Region = rep(c("a","b"), each=100),
                  State =rep(c("NY","MA","FL","GA"), each = 50),
                  Loc = rep(letters[1:20], each = 5),
                  ID = 1:200,
                  count1 = sample(4, 200, replace=T),
                  count2 = sample(4, 200, replace=T))
```

Individual observations are denoted with a unque `ID`. There are three grouping variables for the individual observations: `Region`, `State`, and `Loc`. Lets say that I know the following conditions to be true: 
- When `count1` equals 1 then `count2` should equal 2
- When `count1` equals 2 then `count2` should equal 4
- When `count1` equals 3 then `count2` should equal 1
- When `count1` equals 4 then `count2` should equal 3

I want to answer the following types of questions:
1. How many observations that belong to each grouping variable (`Region`, `State`, `Loc`) are in each level of `count1` and `count2`

2. Which `ID`s are in which level of `count1` and `count2`(and what grouping variables do these `ID`s belong to)
3. How often do the conditions outlined above hold true, and how often do they not hold true
4. For which grouping variables and `ID`s do these conditions hold true, and for which do they not hold true
5. When the conditions do not hold true, what is actually observed (e.g., when `count1` equals 1 then `count2` should equal 2; so when `count1` equals 1 but `count2` does not equal 2, then what does `count2` equal instead).

How can I specify these conditions and produce tidy summary-like tables to answer these questions?
You can think of the levels of `count1` and `count2` as being associated with certain characteristics, and I want understand the relationship between those levels with each other, and with the grouping variables. If anyone has any graphical visualization ideas for these types of questions, that would be very helpful as well!

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to go for questions 1 & 2 although this feels a little involved. I am using `tidyr` `pivot_wider` to create columns for each unique value of `count1` and `count2`. The function `length` in `values_fn` counts the number of elements in the vectors created by `pivot_wider` for relevant combinations. As we need answers for `count1` and `count2` separately I run `pivot_wider` twice. 
Results are then combined with `bind_cols` and superfluous columns are removed.
All of this can probably be improved on with a bit more thought.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(tibble)

set.seed(123)
data <- data.frame(Region = rep(c("a","b"), each=100),
                  State =rep(c("NY","MA","FL","GA"), each = 50),
                  Loc = rep(letters[1:20], each = 5),
                  ID = 1:200,
                  count1 = sample(4, 200, replace=T),
                  count2 = sample(4, 200, replace=T))

# 1. How many observations that belong to each grouping variable (Region, State, Loc) are in each level of count1 and count2
level_count1 <- data %>%
  select(-count2) %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = c(Region, State, Loc),
              values_from = count1,
              values_fn = list(count1 = length),
              names_from = count1,
              names_prefix = "count1_")

level_count2 <- data %>%
  select(-count1) %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = c(Region, State, Loc),
              values_from = count2,
              values_fn = list(count2 = length),
              names_from = count2,
              names_prefix = "count2_") 
level_count <- bind_cols(level_count1, level_count2) %>% select(-Region1, -State1, -Loc1)


# 2. Which IDs are in which level of count1 and count2(and what grouping variables do these IDs belong to)
ID_count1 <- data %>%
  select(-count2) %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = ID,
              values_from = count1,
              values_fn = list(count1 = length),
              names_from = count1,
              names_prefix = "count1_") %>%
  left_join(data %>% select(Region, State, Loc, ID), by = "ID")

ID_count2 <- data %>%
  select(-count1) %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = ID,
              values_from = count2,
              values_fn = list(count2 = length),
              names_from = count2,
              names_prefix = "count2_") %>%
  left_join(data %>% select(Region, State, Loc, ID), by = "ID")
ID_count <- bind_cols(ID_count1, ID_count2) %>% select(-Region1, -State1, -Loc1, -ID)
```

Results are like this:

```
> head(level_count)
# A tibble: 6 x 11
  Region State Loc   count1_3 count1_1 count1_2 count1_4 count2_4 count2_2 count2_1 count2_3
  <fct>  <fct> <fct>    <int>    <int>    <int>    <int>    <int>    <int>    <int>    <int>
1 a      NY    a            3        2       NA       NA        2        1        1        1
2 a      NY    b            2        1        2       NA       NA        2        1        2
3 a      NY    c           NA       NA        3        2       NA        2        2        1
4 a      NY    d            1        3       NA        1        1        3       NA        1
5 a      NY    e            2        3       NA       NA        2        3       NA       NA
6 a      NY    f            1        2        1        1       NA       NA        2        3
```

The value of 3 in the first row of column `count1_3` means that the combination of `Region == "a"`, `State == "NY"` and `Loc == "a"` occurs 3 times for the value 3 for `count1`. Likewise, the value 2 in the second row indicates that the value 3 occurs twice in `count1` for the combination `Region == "a"`, `State == "NY"` and `Loc == "b"`.
`NA` values indicate that 3 does not occur for the given combination of categorical columns. And so on. Is this useful for you?
The approach for ID is similar.